# Rice's Theorem: implication of having an undecidable property

Tags: computability, undecidability, rice-theorem

I understand the assumptions that have to be true about a property or set of properties in a Turing machine description for Rice's Theorem to apply.

But then what?  If a set of Turing machines have an undecidable property, is the language itself necessarily undecidable? Or only if you can find a reduction from a known-undecidable machine is the language undecidable?

What does it really say about a language if it has an undecidable property? Are machines that recognize that language undecidable?

Comment: **Turing** machine, not "turning machine".  Named after Alan Turing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An undecidable property $\pi$ of Turing machines is the same as an undecidable language consisting of all encodings of Turing machines satisfying $\pi$. We identify the property with the language of encodings of Turing machines satisfying the property.

The fact that a language is undecidable just means that no Turing machine decides the language — this is the definition of undecidability. In particular, no machines recognize the language, assuming *recognize* means *decide*; a machine $T$ decides a language $L$ if $T$ terminates on all inputs, on inputs $x \in L$ returns $1$, and on inputs $x \notin L$ returns $0$. A *machine* cannot be undecidable, only a *language* can be undecidable.

Comment: Ok thank that helps me clear up me confusing languages and machines. Let me ask a follow up question: If a language has an undecidable property, then that doesn't 100% mean the language itself is undecidable, correct?

Comment: Languages cannot have undecidable properties, since you cannot give the language as an input to a program, since it is an infinite object.

Answer (score 0):

You are talking about two things here. Consider a non-trivial property $P$ of languages. $P$ can be anything, for instance, does the language contain a string of prime length or not.

Now there are a set of *Turing Machines* whose languages have this property $P$. Let,

$$S = \{\langle M\rangle \mid\text{ Language of M satisfies }P\}\,.$$

Now, Rice's Theorem says that $S$ is undecidable. This means that you cannot build a decider that takes the description of a Turing Machine and tells whether the language of the input machine has a particular non trivial property. It does **NOT** say that for any $L$, ($L \in P $) $L$ is undecidable.

Consider the language $L = \{10\}$. This language $L$ is in $S$ (note that I am saying $L \in S$). Clearly, the language is decidable even though $S$ is not.

Hope that clears your doubt.

Comment: No. Rice's Theorem says that $\{\langle M \rangle \mid \text{Turing machine }M \text{ accepts a language with property }P\}$ is undecidable.

Comment: What does $\langle L\rangle$ mean?

Comment: The answer was horribly wrong before. Hopefully, it makes more sense now.

Comment: It still seems problematic to me.  What does "Language of M and satisfies P" mean?  Do you mean $L(M)$ satisfies $P$?

Comment: Yes. It's supposed to mean L(M) satisfies P. Is the answer okay now?

Comment: David - <O> is the encoding of a O, for any object O. It is simply one of the possible representations of O in the form of a string.